# Setting Envers properties in quarkus

Tags: quarkus, hibernate-envers

Is there a way of changing the name of REV and REVTYPE columns of the Hibernate Envers auditing tables without using persistence.xml in Quarkus?
That would be org.hibernate.envers.revisionFieldName and org.hibernate.envers.revisionTypeFieldName , respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I recently updated the Quarkus Hibernate Envers integration to support all the possible Envers configuration options, so this should now be possible.

Comment: is there any documentation on how to use the configuration with quarkus? do you know on which version of quarkus the update is available?

Comment: @Bentz That was aplied to the  2.5.0.Final version of quarkus.